# Convert String timestamp with offset to Java date

Tags: java, timestamp

I need to convert this timestamp string to a Java `Date` object

```
2014-04-03T14:02:57.182+0200
```

How do I do this? How do I handle the time offset included in the timestamp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
String strdate = "2014-04-03T14:02:57.182+0200";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(strdate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thread-safe alternative from apache commons lang3. First:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat;
```

then:

```
String strdate = "2014-04-03T14:02:57.182+0200";
String dateFormatPattern = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
Date date = FastDateFormat.getInstance(dateFormatPattern).parse(strdate);
System.out.println(date);
```